# Javascript variables use in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image, variables, size

I want to use "screen.availWidth" and "screen.availHeight" to change the size of a image. How can I do it?

Here is my code I want that that work.

`<img src="logoDK.png" alt="" width="screen.availWidth/1.9" height="screen.availHeight/3.84">`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Search MDN and come back with code you wrote is a good first step...

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could works, if you are using query

```
$('#myimage').width(screen.availWidth);  
$('#myimage').height(screen.availHeight);
```

You can use the event resize, to detect windows resize event and update the size.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {

});
```